# Outlook AddIn: CommandBarButton in the existing context menu

Tags: ms-office, outlook-addin

I am trying to do a Outlook AddIn. I have a requirement to have a CommandBarButton
in the existing context menu.
Eg: I need to add a new button "New button" in the "Home" context menu.
Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command Bars were deprecated. They are not used any longer. You need to use the Ribbon XML for customizing context menus in Office applications. You can read more about that in the [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx) article in MSDN.